# gcloud beta ai - PERMISSION_DENIED

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-ai-platform

I'm trying to user the brand new group `ai` from `gcloud beta`. For example

```
gcloud beta ai custom-jobs list
```

It then prompts me to choose a region:

```
Please specify a region:
[1] us-central1
[2] europe-west4
...
```

Whatever region I choose, it asks me to activate the relative API:

```
API [aiplatform.googleapis.com] not enabled on project [xxx].
Would you like to enable and retry (this will take a few minutes)?
(y/N)?
```

Finally, when I say yes, it gives the fatal error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.ai.custom-jobs.list) PERMISSION_DENIED: The caller does not have permission
```

***Debug***

- I can perfectly use the group `ai-platform`, like `gcloud beta ai-platform jobs list`
- The `core.account` from `gcloud config configurations describe xxx` has *Owner* permission
- I tried the same commands on the cloud shell terminal, same result

What am I doing wrong / missing?

Comment: Is this question about enabling API appears each time you run the command or it appeared just once? the command `gcloud beta ai-platform jobs list` uses different API how it was enabled?

Comment: The "enable API" appears only with the `ai` group (never managed to use it), everytime. When I use `ai-platform` it appears as already enabled.

Comment: Yes, but `ai` uses different API than `ai-paltform` so it has to be enabled seperatly,  seems the user does not have permission to do it...

Comment: It seems strange that I can enable all APIs except this one. Furthermore, even on the cloud shell terminal, I'm not able to do it. Keep in mind that I'm Owner of the project, so I think that, at least, on the CS terminal I should have all the permissions.

Comment: do you have any organization structure? or maybe you are using free tier?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same behavior on my testing project (free tier). However I have checked that is no API available that is needed run this command.

You can check your available API's using command:

`gcloud beta services list --available`

But this `gcloud` command (I mean `ai`) is available only in alpha and beta, so it's still in testing phase and it's only possible to provide feedback for this command.